# Detect pixelated images by using opencv and javascript

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, opencv

I'm trying to find out whether user uploaded photo is blur/pixelated. For that i'm using OpenCV4Nodejs package. It only detects blur not the pixelated one. So i found a python code to detect pixelated images but i wanted to do it in node/javascript. I tried converting it but couldn't as i'm new to python. Can someone help me convert it. if cannot then could you please suggest is there any other way we can detect pixelated images?

Python Code:

```
import numpy as np
import Image, ImageChops

im = Image.open('fireworks-pixelate-02.gif')    
im2 = im.transform(im.size, Image.AFFINE, (1,0,1,0,1,1))
im3 = ImageChops.subtract(im, im2)
im3 = np.asarray(im3)
im3 = np.sum(im3,axis=0)[:-1]
mean = np.mean(im3)
peak_spacing = np.diff([i for i,v in enumerate(im3) if v > mean*2])
mean_spacing = np.mean(peak_spacing)
std_spacing = np.std(peak_spacing)
print 'mean gap:', mean_spacing, 'std', std_spacing
```

Comment: funny code... shifts the image by one diagonally, which is a cheap sobel/laplacian filter... then sums that up by pixel columns, hoping to find vertical edges from pixelation. -- TBH, a fourier transform would be more useful. you should see high frequency peaks that are characteristic for grids.

Comment: Appreciate your response @Christoph, Could you please elaborate that, after fourier transform, what we supposed to do next? I've applied the fourier transform and can see high frequency peaks(grid) for the image which is pixelated. Is there a way we can detect it?